# Sharing default group folder between applications in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

I want users to be able to choose a “group” folder/directory when installing the first application on their Windows computer. If/when they then choose to install additional applications, I want the Inno installer to find the first “group” folder/directory that the user installed to, and prepend that folder/directory to the beginning of the suggested App folder/directory name when installing a second application. If the user changes that 'group' folder, then the new group folder should be saved as the new “default” group folder for any subsequent installations (and the first app installed is then in an ‘orphan’ folder).

I expect the way to do this is with a registry entry for “default installation folder group”? See diagram that hopefully clarifies my question a bit with examples.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The installers made in Inno Setup store the selected "group" folder to

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\AppId_is1]
"Inno Setup: Icon Group"="Group"
```

(Or to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` if the installer is not started with Administrator privileges).

Note that the path is application specific (the `AppId` is the installer's id).

So if you decide to use this key, you would have to scan keys of all your applications. And you wouldn't know which application was installed the last time anyway.

---

So I believe you should create your own registry key to store the group to.

To save the selected group, you can do with a standard Inno Setup `[Registry]` section:

```
[Registry]
Root: HKLM; Subkey: "Software\My Company"; ValueType: string; \
  ValueName: "GlobalGroup"; ValueData: "{groupname}"
```

Though to load it, you have to script it:

```pascal
[Code]

procedure InitializeWizard();
var
  GlobalGroup: string;
begin
  if RegQueryStringValue(
       HKLM, 'Software\My Company', 'GlobalGroup', GlobalGroup) then
  begin
    Log('Global group found: ' + GlobalGroup);
    WizardForm.GroupEdit.Text := GlobalGroup;
  end
    else
  begin
    Log('Global group not found');
  end;
end;
```

---

Note that the registry entry won't be deleted when all applications are uninstalled. So the global group survives global uninstallation. You would have to implement a reference counter to deal with that, if it is a problem.

---

If I understand correctly, you actually share just a part of the group name (first-level directory?). So you may need some logic when choosing what to save in registry. In that case, you better script the saving too:

```pascal
procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
var
  GlobalGroup: string;
begin
  if CurStep = ssDone then
  begin
    GlobalGroup := ExpandConstant('{groupname}');
    Log('Saving global group: ' + GlobalGroup);

    if RegWriteStringValue(
         HKLM, 'Software\My Company', 'GlobalGroup', GlobalGroup) then
    begin
      Log('Global group saved');
    end
      else
    begin
      Log('Error saving global group');
    end;
  end;
end;
```